# Room object replace old record although mustn't do it

Tags: java, android, android-room

I have many-to-many relation.

I have room object (`PurchaseRecord`) with two `long` fields - id of entities in relationship. Object have `primaryKeys` - both field. But when I insert new object, it replace old with equals `categoryId`. I did try to change `@OnConflictStrategy` (include `IGNORE`, `REPLACE` and `ABORT`), but it haven't result.

To see db I use [inloop.github.io/sqlite-viewer](https://inloop.github.io/sqlite-viewer)

`PurchaseRecord`

```
@Entity(tableName = "purchases_categories", foreignKeys = {
        @ForeignKey(entity = Purchase.class, childColumns = "purchaseId", parentColumns = "id",
                onDelete = CASCADE),
        @ForeignKey(entity = Category.class, childColumns = "categoryId", parentColumns = "id",
                onDelete = CASCADE)},
        primaryKeys = {"purchaseId", "categoryId"})
public class PurchasesCategories {
    @ColumnInfo(index = true)
    long purchaseId;
    @ColumnInfo(index = true)
    long categoryId;

    public PurchasesCategories(long purchaseId, long categoryId) {
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
        this.purchaseId = purchaseId;
    }
}
```

Insert record (`ViewModel` class)

```
    public void addItem(PurchaseRecord record) {
        new ItemInserter(adapter, dao, data, record).execute();
    }

    private static class ItemInserter extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        PurchaseAdapter adapter;
        private MyDAO dao;
        private List<PurchaseRecord> data;
        private PurchaseRecord record;

        public ItemInserter(PurchaseAdapter adapter, MyDAO dao, List<PurchaseRecord> data, PurchaseRecord record) {
            this.adapter = adapter;
            this.dao = dao;
            this.data = data;
            this.record = record;
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... aVoid) {
            record.getPurchase().setId(dao.insert(record.getPurchase()));
            for (Category category : record.getCategories()) {
                category.setId(dao.insert(category));
                dao.insert(new PurchasesCategories(record.getPurchase().getId(), category.getId()));
            }
            data.add(record);
            ViewModel.getInstance().sortData();

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
```

[Repository](https://github.com/ProMix0/FinanceApp)

Answer (score 0):

> But when I insert new object, it replace old with equals categoryId

Assuming that you mean for an existing category, then that is what you want.

- i.e. As you have a unique index on the category name, you only want 1 category and for that to reference/link/map to any purchases that use that category.

Although when using REPLACE what it does is increase the id of the category (which is a little wasteful)

However, what you probably want to do is use the category if it already exists.

If you added a dao such as :-

```
@Query("SELECT id FROM categories WHERE name =:name")
long ifCategoryExists(String name);
```

and then changed you code to be :-

```
        for (Category category : record.getCategories()) {
            category.setId(dao.ifCategoryExists(category.getName()));
            if (category.getId() < 1) category.setId(dao.insert(category));
            dao.insert(new PurchasesCategories(record.getPurchase().getId(), category.getId()));
        }
```

Then the existing category would be used if the category already existed.

I would also suggest that instead of using `data.add(record)` that you let the fragment show what is in the database and thus that you instead use:-

```
data.clear();
data.addAll(dao.getAllPurchases());
```

Then the displayed data will be in sync with what is actually in the database.

Comment: `Insert` return id of inserted or already existing category. I did check it.

Comment: And when I insert, for example, `PurchaseRecord(1, 2)`, it replace `PurchaseRecord(3, 2)`
A little later I try to find minimal code